# Returning file not found error

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to read a file called "files.txt" and return each line in order. I receive and catch a **no such file or directory** when I'm sure the text file is in my working directory. Is there something improper about the code?

```
def main():
    FileRead()

def ReadFile(filename):
    files = open(filename)
    lines = files.readlines()

    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        print(index, "=", line)

def FileRead():
    try:
        ReadFile("files.txt")

    except IOError as e:
        print("Could not open file:", e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Are you sure your working directory is where you think it is? Try calling `os.getcwd()` in `main()` to determine that. Then `os.listdir()` to verify that `files.txt` is actually in the directory that python thinks it's in.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy, I actually found a solution by using the full path to files.txt. I have confirmed the file is in the same folder as my .py script, but for some reason this works for other scripts I've worked on but not this one. Not sure why. Thanks for your help!